# Adding Gaussian noise to each element of rows of a matrix efficiently

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `m`:

```
set.seed(1)
m = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10) # my data is not a random matrix in reality, but it should not matter
```

I want to add 5% `Gaussian` noise to each row of the matrix. Each element of a row of the matrix should get a different random noise. The random values should be calculated row-wise, based on the `sd` of each row.

So far, I have implemented it with a `for` `loop` and it seems to do the job:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
        m[i, ] = m[i, ] + rnorm(n = ncol(m), mean = 0, sd = sd(m[i, ]) * 0.05)
}
```

However, my real data is very large and I want to vectorize this implementation as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be like this...

```
#calculate the sd for each row...
sds <- apply(m, 1, sd)

#generate all noise factors at once and just add to m...
m <- m + rnorm(nrow(m) * ncol(m), mean = 0, sd = sds * 0.05)
```

This works because `sds` will be recycled for each column.  In general these matrix operations are very fast in R.

Comment: `nrow(m) * ncol(m)` == `length(m)` when `m` is a matrix

Comment: Thats more elegant than my solution - didn't know about the recycling. Thanks

Comment: If you are happy to use non-`base` packages, I think `matrixStats::rowSds` is faster than `apply`.

Comment: Wow! This runs in like 2 seconds on a `300000 x 300` matrix. :) But I cannot wrap my head around how this "recycling" works. Does each row still get different random noise for each element?

Comment: @bird The `rnorm` call wants `nrow * ncol` values of `sd`, but `sds` is only `nrow` long, so it just repeats it as many times as is needed.  It is a general feature of R that is often very useful! `m` is just a vector (with matrix attributes) that holds the matrix columns one after the other.  So the noise values correspond to the rows as they get wrapped around.

Comment: @bird Just another way of expressing the latter part: in R matrices are in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). Thus, a matrix is filled with values in that order (but note the `byrow` argument in `matrix`). Because the random values are generated using  `sd` which are calculated row-wise and recycled in `rnorm` , the values will end up in the correct rows in a column-major fill order.

Answer (score 1):

This sould do the trick:

```
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
m = matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

> m
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291
[2,]  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247
[3,] -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814
```

Calculate `sd` by row

```
m_sd <- apply(m, 1, sd)
```

Calculate noise by row and put it in a matrix

```
m_noise <- map(m_sd, rnorm, n = nrow(m), mean = 0) %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Add original and noise matrix

```
m + m_noise * 0.05

> m + m_noise * 0.05
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.6434161  1.6792503 0.5090823
[2,]  0.1747117  0.2976669 0.7544979
[3,] -0.8374496 -0.8211245 0.6140321
```